# Windows Azure pack on server 2012 R2 will use onpremises server infrastrucutre or Microsoft Public azure infrastrucutre

Tags: azure

I just started reading Windows Azure pack and I want to confirm that this Windows azure pack will use our on premises windows 2012 R2 or SCVMM2012  infrastructure not the windows azure public cloud infrastructure

but we can use almost the same features that we can use in windows azure public cloud after building this windows azure pack infrastructure on on-premises server 2012.

is this correct please give me your feedback ?

Comment: What is your question about programming?

Answer (score 0):

You will have access to a subset of the entire Azure offering when running this pack on-premise.  Features bundled include: management portals for user and admin self-service, service management API, Web Sites, Virtual Machines, Service Bus, SQL and MySQL support.

You don't have access to Azure SQL Database, Mobile or Media Services and other PaaS (Platform-as-a-Service) offerings.

Also, overtime you'll find that the public cloud offering will be updated more quickly than on-premise (which is similar to how TFService & on-prem TFS is works today).